# C# - How to create an instance with an generic type that requires an generic type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a class that takes two generic parameters, e.g. .
In the class i want to create an instance of T1 but T1 requires T2 as generic param, e.g. new T1();

But VS says: "CS0307 Typeparameter 'Ttable' can not be used with Type-Args" (translated from german)

Is there any way to do this in current dotNet (c#) code or is this simply not possible?

```
//the IDefaultInterface is needed for the parent-class!
public class ParentClass<T1, T2> : IDefaultInterface 
        where T1: ChildClass<Tfile>, new()
        where T2: GrandChildClass, new()
    {
        private T1<T2> child_instance = new T1<T2>();
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It seems that you want a new child instance with generic type GrandChildClass, so when you create the constraints, change it to `where T1 : ChildClass<T2>, new() ` then you can `private T1 child_instance = new T1();`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, i didn't think of that way, you are the Hero of my Day! :D